# Roll-up summary can't access field for filter criteria

Tags: roll-up-summary

I got an issue with roll-up summary field, I'm trying to create a cumulative summary field that count the number of Contact with the role X associated to my Account.

So I go to Account which is the parent, I add a new field --> roll-up summary --> I choose Associated Contact --> Count and then on filter criteria I can choose fields but my Role field isn't in the list (And Role is a field of my Associated contact custom object), only few fields of my Associated contact custom object are in the list.

Do you know why my Role Field isn't on the list ? My Role field is a multi-select pick-list that's maybe why I can't access it but is there a way to count my contact associated to my account filtered by Role ? I really need to do this.

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Right - you can't use multi-select picklists to filter a roll-up summary field. You've got a couple options:

1. Ditch that multi-select picklist and replace it with a single-select picklist, because MSPs are trash and almost always create more problems than they solve.
2. Build a formula field on your Associated Contact object, and filter on that. Use a Boolean formula that is the filter you want for your roll-up summary. Then you just use the formula field being TRUE in the roll-up summary's filter. So if you want to filter for two specific roles:

   INCLUDES(Roles__c, "Business User") || INCLUDES(Roles__c, "Economic Decision Maker")

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used the 2nd option and it works really well

Answer (score 0):

Your field has to be a lookup with a Master-Detail relationship in order to show up in summary fields like that. [Here is a cool trailhead that can show you how to do that.](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/data_modeling/object_relationships) Contacts don't have that by default, but it seems you have a custom object built for this. So I just want to make sure that was the relationship.

In order to get your picklist to work like that, I believe you need to build either a flow or APEX code. [Here seems to be a similar example.](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000iYAaQAM) [Another example that uses Rollup Helper](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000e5ohQAA), which is a pretty common tool.